# How do you use custom labelComponents in victory-native?

Tags: javascript, victory-charts

The top chart uses regular labels. The bottom is using a `labelCompoent` prop custom label.
It seems custom labels are being absolute positioned.

[image]

[Here is an Expo Snack.](https://snack.expo.io/@gollyjer/victory-labels-testing)  (click to view the problem on Android and iOS).

And here is the code.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { VictoryBar } from 'victory-native';
import svg from 'react-native-svg';

const CustomLabel = props => <Text>{props.text}</Text>;

const App = () => {
  const data = [
    { x: 0, y: 1, label: 'Test 1' },
    { x: 1, y: 2, label: 'Test 2' },
    { x: 2, y: 3, label: 'Test 3' },
  ];

  const w = Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.9;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <VictoryBar data={data} width={w} />
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <VictoryBar data={data} width={w} labelComponent={<CustomLabel />} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    borderWidth: 3,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});

export default App;
```

How can I get custom labels positioning properly?

Comment: The `CustomLabel` component will receive the bar's offset - `x` and `y` into the props. You can use it into a `<G>` wrapper for your custom component. But It doesn't provide you the real offset of the label... especially if the label is centered. You check my snack - https://snack.expo.io/@hristoeftimov/victory-labels-testing